# No module named 'flask_cors' when using gunicorn

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gunicorn

My application runs normally when running using `python run.py` but when running using gunicorn `gunicorn run:app` it gives 'flask_cors' module not found error.

I have created a basic application to make it easier to understand, I have debugged it a lot but didn't work, as it's running fine with `python run.py` so it should be running when using gunicorn, I think I do not actually understand how gunicorn is actually importing that it's leading to this error.

Working Directory

```
.
├── flaskblog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── routes.py
├── requirements.txt
└── run.py

1 directory, 4 files
```

`__init__.py` file

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)

from flaskblog import routes
```

routes.py file

```
from flaskblog import app
from flask_cors import cross_origin


@app.route("/")
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def home():
    return "home"
```

run.py file

```
from flaskblog import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask
gunicorn
flask-cors
```

edit:

I run the program again to get the error trace, and this time it worked?
It started at '127.0.0.1:8000' so I used `gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0 run:app`

How is it working now?

If you have a better title for the question then please edit it, as now my issue is it's strange behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Deleted the pycache and created the environment again, this time it worked as it should be and hosted on heroku successfully.
Inside my procfile

```
web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi
web: gunicorn run:app
```